# Mirroring to object will not apply

Tags: mirror

[image: mirroring cylinders] I am trying to mirror the cylinder and would like the shelter to be the mirror object. But no way, I have tried almost anything.

Comment: Are you trying to mirror the cylinder using the modifier or have already created a cylinder and want to mirror it over the axis?

Comment: the cylinder the original one is on the left, in the picture I am applying a mirror modifier

Comment: The mirror seems to be working fine. Are you trying to apply the modifier or trying to mirror the shelter?

Comment: you've chosen the X axis, are you not trying to mirror on the Y axis?

Comment: Solved. First i placed the 3d cursor in the middle of the short side of the shelter, than I set the to the 3d cursor and eventually the mirroring was ok.